# How to prevent labels moving other parts of a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a simple graph in Tikz. The problem is when I add a label outside of a node, it somehow moves other parts of a graph. For instance, in the example below, `G` is pushed toward left due to the label `O`.

Is there any way to tell Tikz to not consider space occupied by labels and draw the graph as if there was not label at all? I tried to use `\mathllap{}`. It helps slightly but even empty labels affect the graph.

Thanks

[image]

Working example

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows.meta,
    graphs,
    matrix,
    positioning,
}
\tikzset{
    o/.style={
      draw, circle, minimum width=5mm, minimum height=5mm, thick,
      fill=black,
    },
    u/.style={
      draw, circle, minimum width=5mm, minimum height=5mm, thick,
      fill=white
    },
    m/.style={
      draw, circle, minimum width=5mm, minimum height=5mm, thick,
      fill=black!30,
    },
}


\begin{document}

{%
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (v) [
      matrix of math nodes,
      column sep=2.5mm,
      row sep=12mm,
  ] {
      |[u,label=above:{G}]| && |[u,label=above:{A}]| & \\
      & |[m,label=left:{\mathllap{O}}]| && |[o,label=right:{C}]| \\
      && |[o,label=below:\hat{O}]| & \\
  };
  \graph[edges={>=Latex, semithick, color=black}] {
      (v-1-1) -> (v-2-2);
      (v-1-3) -> {(v-2-2), (v-2-4)};
      (v-2-2) -> (v-3-3);
      (v-2-4) -> (v-3-3);
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}\par}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try using `\makebox[0pt]{O}`, but that requires that you tweak the placement. Since you are using a `matrix of math nodes`, the label is affecting the width of the cell. For a graph, perhaps not using a matrix might be better.

Comment: Since a label is actually just another node, you can add the labels after the matrix is done using the (automatic) node names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a different approach. Set the coordinates manually and adjust the spacing by setting `xscale` and `yscale`. To shorten the code, the coordinates of each node can be placed in a list where each entry has the form `x/y/s/l/t`, where the coordinates are `(x,y)`, the style is `s`, the label is `l` and the angle of the label relative to the node is `t`. The nodes are automatically numbered so arrows can be drawn in a second loop. Complete code is below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    o/.style={
      draw, circle, minimum width=5mm, minimum height=5mm, thick,
      fill=black,
    },
    u/.style={
      draw, circle, minimum width=5mm, minimum height=5mm, thick,
      fill=white
    },
    m/.style={
      draw, circle, minimum width=5mm, minimum height=5mm, thick,
      fill=black!30,
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.75,yscale=1.5]
\foreach \x/\y/\s/\l/\t[count=\n] in {-2/2/u/G/90,0/2/u/A/90,-1/1/m/O/180,1/1/o/C/0,0/0/o/\hat{O}/270}
    \node[\s,label=\t:{$\l$}] (n\n) at (\x,\y){};
\foreach \a/\b in {1/3,2/3,2/4,3/5,4/5} \draw[semithick, -latex](n\a)--(n\b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like a matrix, as well. I read through the first chapters of TikZ and managed to draw this graph, manually, via coordinates, and then read about the `positioning` library. I did not realise you can apply so many variables in `foreach`!